# Make Discussions posts available in SEDE

Tags: feature-request, data-explorer, discussions-space

I want to do analysis on Discussions with SEDE. I'm not sure how exactly this would work-whether a new table is needed due to the structural differences, but I can't currently think of why it couldn't work as a new post type in the `Posts` table, making use of the `ParentId` to handle nesting. Unless you want to have two types of `ParentId`- one for the parent discussion, and one for the parent thread. I don't care too much as long as it's possible in a performant manner to distinguish whether something is the discussion starter, a sub-thread, or a reply in a sub-thread.

Comment: I don't see this happening as the discussions space is still experimental (even though it's getting expanded, this will probably get [meta-tag:status-deferred]). Have we had Documentation available in SEDE? That said, I have upvoted this as it is a legitimate request.